# Search in multiple columns over multiple tabs with =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula

xBeen searching for the question on Stack without any results. I have made the following formula which works well and list if an client has made a First order or an repeat order. But now it also needs to search in other tabs (with the data of older years, 2022, 2021 etc) Formula:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(K339; (K5:K338);0)); "Repeat order"; "First order")`

How do I fix that? I tried the following for example, but that is not working:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(K339; (K5:K338&K445:K448);0)); "Repeat order"; "First order")`

Comment: You could try : `=SWITCH(SUM(1-ISNA(MATCH(VSTACK(Sheet1!K5:K338;Sheet2!&K445:K448);K339;0)));0;"None";1;"First Order";"Repeat Order")`

Answer (score 0):

MATCH requires a range or an array of single dimension, cant you add the data from provious years in the same table?

Else you should try something like:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(K339; (K5:K338);0));ISNUMBER(MATCH(K339; (K445:K448);0)); "Repeat order"; "First order")
```